# Jquery - Replace fontawesome icons dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatable

In datatable i try something like that

```
  rowCallback: function (row: any, data: any, index: any) {
            var api = this.api();
            $(row).find(".nonces").off('click').on('click', () => {
              $('td', row).find($(".fa-bug")).removeClass('fa-bug').addClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse');
              self.modalNonces(data, row);
            })
    
          },

      modalNonces(data, row){
      //Process finish
     $('td', row).find($(".fa-spinner fa-pulse")).removeClass('fa-spinner fa-pulse').addClass('fa-bug');
```

}

The problem: When process finish doesn't remove class spinner so i can´t bind new icon when process finished. So, what´s the rigth way to remove / show icon dynamically?

Comment: what are you display at console for `$('td', row).find($(".fa-spinner fa-pulse")).length`  are you ok with your selector?

Comment: Can you please create the fiddle?

Comment: use `$('td', row).find(".fa-bug") ...` instead of passing jquery object in selector